# False proof that boundedly convexly complete sequence is norm null: where is the issue?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces

A given sequence $(x_{i})_{i}$ in a Banach space $X$ is said to be series bounded if $\sup_{n}\left\Vert\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right\Vert<\infty$. Suppose now that $(x_{i})_{i}$ is also Schauder basic and semi-normalized. If, for every sequence of scalars $(a_{i})_{i}$ such that $(a_{i}x_{i})_{i}$ is series bounded, it follows that
\begin{equation*} \lim_{n\to\infty}\left\Vert\sum_{i\in F_{n}}a_{i}x_{i}\right\Vert=0 \text{ if } \sup_{n}\sum_{i\in F_{n}}|a_{i}|<\infty \end{equation*}
where $F_{1},F_{2},\ldots$ are consecutive finite subets of $\mathbb{N}$, then $(x_{i})_{i}$ is said to be boundedly convexly complete (b.c.c.). I seem to have proved that a b.c.c. sequence $(x_{i})_{i}$ is norm null, but I know that this cannot be true because a b.c.c. sequence is semi-normalized. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find the mistake in my proof (below). Can anyone point out the issue?

Let $(x_{i})_{i}$ be semi-normalized and Schauder basic and let $F_{n}=\{n\}$. Note that every positive integer $i$ can be expressed in the form $i=R_{i}\pi+r_{i}$ for some non-negative integer $R_{i}$ and for some real number $r_{i}\in[0,\pi)$. Now, let $a_{i}=\sin(r_{i})\geq 0$. It follows that for $C=\sup_{i}\|x_{i}\|<\infty$,
\begin{equation*} \left\Vert\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}x_{i}\right\Vert \leq C\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sin(r_{i}) =C\left[\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{2})-\cos(n+\frac{1}{2})}{2\sin(\frac{1}{2})}\right]\leq \frac{C}{\sin(\frac{1}{2})} \end{equation*}
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $(a_{i}x_{i})_{i}$ is series bounded, where the middle equality follows from the trigonometric product-sum identity $2\sin(i)\sin(\frac{1}{2})=\cos(i-\frac{1}{2})-\cos(i+\frac{1}{2})$ and a telescoping sum. Clearly, $\sup_{n}\sum_{i\in F_{n}}|a_{i}|=\sup_{n}|\sin(r_{n})|\leq 1$ as well, so applying the b.c.c. condition, we have:
\begin{equation*} 0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\Vert\sum_{i\in F_{n}}a_{i}x_{i}\right\Vert=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|\sin(r_{n})x_{n}\|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(r_{n})\|x_{n}\|\end{equation*}
which yields a contradiction if $\|x_{n}\|$ does not converge to zero (because the RHS limit does not exist in this case).

For reference, the definitions of series boundedness, b.c.c., and similar notions can all be found in [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2001-353-05/S0002-9947-01-02711-8/S0002-9947-01-02711-8.pdf) 2001 paper from Argyros and Gasparis. They established a dichotomy theorem for weakly null sequences in this paper having to do with b.c.c. sequences.

I also apologize in advance if the mistake in my proof is trivial - it's late and I'm tired